# Pip thrift and impyla not installing on Linux

Tags: python, hadoop, centos, pip, impyla

I'm trying to get pip (3.6) to install the packages thrift-sasl, thrift-py and impyla, on CentOS 6, and I keep getting this error.

> > > Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-rv4_laqv/thriftpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hogvggj3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rv4_laqv/thriftpy/

Things I have tried

- Updating pip
- Installing/updating setuptools
- yum install gcc-c++ python-devel.x86_64 cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64

Any suggestions or insights?

Comment: That error is super vague. Sorry, but looks like best bet is to file an issue on the tracker.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll give that a go :X